# Ordinary Differential Equations (global stabilty)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Let $n \geq 2$ be an integer. I am analyzing a set of differential equations as follows:
\begin{align*}
    \dot{x}_1 &:=f_1(x_1,x_2) = x_1^{n} + n x_1^{n-1}(1-x_1-x_2) + n x_1(1-x_1-x_2)^{n-1}-x_1\\
    \dot{x}_2 &:=f_2(x_1,x_2) = x_2^{n} - x_2,
\end{align*}
where $x_1,x_2 \in [0,1].$

It is clear that the restpoints of the above system are $(0,1)$ and $(1,0).$ I verfied that the Jacobian evaluated at $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ is given by,
\begin{align*}
    J(0,1) &= \begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}\\ 
  \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}
\end{pmatrix}_{\big|(x_1,x_2)=(0,1)}=\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 0\\ 
  0 & n-1
\end{pmatrix}\\
J(1,0) &= \begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}\\ 
  \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}
\end{pmatrix}_{\big|(x_1,x_2)=(1,0)}=\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & -n\\ 
  0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

With the Jacobian analysis, I can conclude that $(0,1)$ is unstable and $(1,0)$ is locally stable. Numeric analysis which I performed shows that $(1,0)$ is almost globally asymptotically stable (meaning that all the trajectories starting from an interior state converge to $(1,0)$). Could someone point me to a result which I can use to establish global stability of $(1,0)$ analytically? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Perhaps the [Hartman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem) Theorem may be of use! Which states; Theorem: (Hartman)\
If $\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$ is a hyperbolic fixed point for $\dot{\textbf{x}}=f(\textbf{x})$, then there is a continuous invertible map $h$, defined on a neighbourhood of $\textbf{0}$, which takes two orbits of the non-linear flow to those of the linearised flow.

Comment: The second equation gives diverging solutions for $x_2>1$, and also for $x_2<-1$ if $n$ is odd. The claim of global stability is not justified.

Comment: The state space is $[0,1]^2$ not $\mathbf{R}^2.$ So the question would make sense, no?

Comment: Yes, all trajectories stay inside the square, thus have to end somewhere, and only 2 can end in the saddle point. All the others converge towards the sink, provided there are no limit cycles.

Comment: Are there any general sufficient conditions which I can use to show that a limit cycle does not exist in my example ?

Comment: It would have a stationary point inside. But since all stationary points are accounted for, this is not possible.